# Get reputation Badge from given score

Tags: performance, comparative-review, go

I have written code that gets the reputation badge from given score like this:

I use an `if`-`else` statement here:

```
func GetReputationBadge2(score int) string {

    badge := "badges-off.jpg"
    if score >= 50001 { // Diamond
        badge = "diamond-1.gif"
        if score >= 500001 {
            badge = "diamond-5.gif"
        } else if score >= 200001 {
            badge = "diamond-4.gif"
        } else if score >= 150001 {
            badge = "diamond-3.gif"
        } else if score >= 100001 {
            badge = "diamond-2.gif"
        }
    } else if score >= 4501 { // Gold
        badge = "gold-1.gif"
        if score >= 45001 {
            badge = "gold-5.gif"
        } else if score >= 30001 {
            badge = "gold-4.gif"
        } else if score >= 15001 {
            badge = "gold-3.gif"
        } else if score >= 10001 {
            badge = "gold-4.gif"
        }
    }

    return badge
}
```

I was kinda thinking that I could make it better using a `switch`-`case` statement:

```
func GetReputationBadge(score int) string {

    badge := "badges-off.jpg"
    caseSwitch := true
    switch caseSwitch {
    case score >= 50001:
        badge = "diamond-1.gif"

        switch caseSwitch {
        case score >= 500001:
            badge = "diamond-5.gif"
        case score >= 200001:
            badge = "diamond-4.gif"
        case score >= 150001:
            badge = "diamond-3.gif"
        case score >= 100001:
            badge = "diamond-2.gif"

        }

    case score >= 4501:
        badge = "gold-1.gif"

        switch caseSwitch {
        case score >= 45001:
            badge = "gold-5.gif"
        case score >= 30001:
            badge = "gold-4.gif"
        case score >= 15001:
            badge = "gold-3.gif"
        case score >= 10001:
            badge = "gold-2.gif"

        }

    default:
        return badge
    }

    return badge
}
```

Notice that I'm comparing `boolean` in the `switch`-`case` statement. Which are better for performance: using `if`-`else` or switch-case statement in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch` is usually easier to read instead of a long if-else chain.

---

You really don't need to write a `switch` like this:

> ```
>     caseSwitch := true
>     switch caseSwitch {
> ```

Replace with simply:

```
    switch {
```

---

There's no need to nest `switch` cases.
It will be simpler and easier to understand to flatten the conditions.
Also, there's no need for the `badge` variable,
you can just return directly.

```
switch {
case score >= 500001:
    return "diamond-5.gif"
case score >= 200001:
    return "diamond-4.gif"
case score >= 150001:
    return "diamond-3.gif"
case score >= 100001:
    return "diamond-2.gif"
case score >= 50001:
    return "diamond-1.gif"
case score >= 45001:
    return "gold-5.gif"
case score >= 30001:
    return "gold-4.gif"
case score >= 15001:
    return "gold-3.gif"
case score >= 10001:
    return "gold-2.gif"
case score >= 4501:
    return "gold-1.gif"
default:
    return "badges-off.jpg"
}
```

---

What will be even better is making an array with values corresponding to the range start and image name pairs.
Then instead of a `switch`,
you could iterate over the values until you find the right range and return the image.

And what will be best is, instead of iterating over the values,
use binary search to find the right value faster.

Answer (score 2):

For just a few items, the difference is small. If you have many items you should definitely use a switch.

This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566229/go-switch-string-efficiency

Comment: since I'm comparing boolean in switch-case statement, is it going to decrease the performance?